# how to remove some entries from json file using python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

How to remove some entries from a JSON file using python?

I have a JSON file that looks like this:

```
json_data = [
    {
        "authType": "ldap",
        "password": "",
        "permissions": [
            {
                "collections": [
                    "aks9099",
                    "aks9098",
                    "aks9100",
                    "aks9101",
                    "aks9102",
                    "aks9103"
                    
                ],
                "project": "Central Project"
            }
        ],
        "role": "devSecOps",
        "username": "chinq.n@example.com"
    },
    {
        "authType": "ldap",
        "password": "",
        "permissions": [
            {
                "collections": [
                    "aks9099",
                    "aks9098",
                    "aks9100",
                    "aks9101",
                    "aks9102",
                    "aks9103"
                ],
                "project": "Central Project"
            }
        ],
        "role": "devSecOps",
        "username": "chinw.d@example.com"
    },
    {
        "authType": "ldap",
        "password": "",
        "permissions": [
            {
                "collections": [
                    "aks9099",
                    "aks9098",
                    "aks9100",
                    "aks9101",
                    "aks9102",
                    "aks9103"
                ],
                "project": "Central Project"
            }
        ],
        "role": "devSecOps",
        "username": "chins.b@example.com"
    },
    {
        "authType": "ldap",
        "password": "",
        "permissions": [
            {
                "collections": [
                    "aks9099",
                    "aks9098",
                    "aks9100",
                    "aks9101",
                    "aks9102",
                    "aks9103"
                ],
                "project": "Central Project"
            }
        ],
        "role": "devSecOps",
        "username": "chini.a@example.com"
    }
]
```

I would like to remove `aks9098`, `aks9099`, and `aks9103` from the list. The expected result should look like this:

```
[
    {
        "authType": "ldap",
        "password": "",
        "permissions": [
            {
                "collections": [
                    "aks9100",
                    "aks9101",
                    "aks9102"                    
                ],
                "project": "Central Project"
            }
        ],
        "role": "devSecOps",
        "username": "chinq.n@example.com"
    },
    {
        "authType": "ldap",
        "password": "",
        "permissions": [
            {
                "collections": [
                    "aks9100",
                    "aks9101",
                    "aks9102"
                ],
                "project": "Central Project"
            }
        ],
        "role": "devSecOps",
        "username": "chinw.d@example.com"
    },
    {
        "authType": "ldap",
        "password": "",
        "permissions": [
            {
                "collections": [
                    "aks9100",
                    "aks9101",
                    "aks9102"
                ],
                "project": "Central Project"
            }
        ],
        "role": "devSecOps",
        "username": "chins.b@example.com"
    },
    {
        "authType": "ldap",
        "password": "",
        "permissions": [
            {
                "collections": [
                    "aks9100",
                    "aks9101",
                    "aks9102"            
                ],
                "project": "Central Project"
            }
        ],
        "role": "devSecOps",
        "username": "chini.a@example.com"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can analyse recursively you input data and remove all forbidden values:

```
def filter_data(data, forbidden_values):
    if isinstance(data, str):
        return data
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        return {
            key: filter_data(value, forbidden_values) for key, value in data.items()
        }
    if isinstance(data, list):
        return [
            filter_data(value, forbidden_values)
            for value in data
            if value not in forbidden_values
        ]


forbidden_values = ["aks9098", "aks9099", "aks9103"]
filtered_data = filter_data(json_data, forbidden_values)
```